# how-to silence PHP Session GC Cron

Tags: php, logging, cron, debian

I'm running **Debian** with **PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14**.
There are several cronjobs that gc clean my php sessions:

---

```
(cron.d)09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete
(crontab)47 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
(crontab)45 0 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
(crontab)34 1 * * 7 root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
(crontab)44 3 4 * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

These Crons throw....

...**cron.log** lines

```
Jan  4 11:47:01 flowl /USR/SBIN/CRON[3976]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan  4 12:09:01 flowl /USR/SBIN/CRON[3983]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete)
```

...**auth.log** lines

```
Jan  4 12:09:01 flowl CRON[3982]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)`
Jan  4 12:09:01 flowl CRON[3982]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`
```

---

How do I remove (all these annoying) cron logs from (at least) auth.log?
im not looking into cron.log that often I could life just with these.

Thanks in advance!
Dan

Comment: There is no way to suppress the cron.log or auth.log lines, nor should you attempt to do so.  You can suppress the email though.  Can you edit your question with the actual *contents* of the email?  That will help us determine how to best silence it.

Comment: I've read of supressing cron/auth log lines in /etc/syslog.conf maybe or adding > /dev/null at the end of output generating lines.
The mails said that I was loading a PHP module twice, I could fix that and dont recieve any more emails, thx for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take from http://blog.flowl.info/2013/reduce-syslog-logging-io-raspberrypi/:
As rsyslog replaced syslog, we can do the following:

in `/etc/rsyslogd.conf`:
replace `auth,authpriv.* /var/log/auth.log`

by:

```
:msg, contains, "pam_unix(cron:session)" ~
auth,authpriv.* /var/log/auth.log
```

same goes for other log files